# ubuntu keeps loging me out randomly

Tags: login, login-screen

I have been having this problem recently:
Ubuntu keeps **loging me out** randomly even when I am **actively moving the mouse** and **pressing
keys.**

The screen goes **blank** and  there is this cursor thing at the top left of the screen for a few seconds and I find my self at the **login screen**.

I have found other questions on this they don't seem to **help**.

Comment: That's not a logout. That's a Desktop Crash. Look in /var/crash for .crash files that will explain the problem in great technical detail.

Comment: Providing your OS & release is helpful.  Did you add any extensions to your desktop?  (if an extension crashes, the GNOME desktop itself will be brought down (crash), so ensure the extensions are intended for your *unstated* GNOME desktop version)

Comment: it is okay now i restored it from timeshift

Comment: @floatingCatsAndDogs: what have you restored from timeshift?